# Filter MySQL Query By DateTime Stored As Varchar

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, varchar

I'm trying to filter a MySQL query by a field that stores datetime values, but uses a varchar data type.

Example data:
*16:56:41 01/14/21 GMT*

Example code:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datetime,'%H:%i:%S %m/%d/%y') BETWEEN '00:00:00 01/14/21' AND '23:59:59 01/14/21'"
```

The query is currently returning nothing at all. However the code below works:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: DATETIME ina varchar() Woops. Can that be fixed?

Comment: I know right, ideally would be DATETIME but just need to work with what we have been supplied with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `STR_TO_DATE` is correct, but your date literals are off.  Fix them, and your query should work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datetime,'%H:%i:%S %m/%d/%y') >= '2021-01-14' AND
      STR_TO_DATE(datetime,'%H:%i:%S %m/%d/%y') <  '2021-01-15';
```

The above assumes that you want records occurring on 14th January, 2021, proper.  Note that we don't need to even include the H:M:S components and can just use date literals.

It would be best to make your `datetime` column a proper datetime type column, rather than text.  This would avoid the need to use `STR_TO_DATE`.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much for your help.